# How to make the tf.gradients() function work in multiple gpu?

Tags: tensorflow

Since the gradients will get 'out of memory' error, how can I run the gradient function in multiple gpus?

```
    with tf.device('gpu:1'):
        trainable_variables = tf.trainable_variables()
        grads = tf.gradients(self.loss, trainable_variables)

    with tf.device('/gpu:2'):
        var1=trainable_variables[60:107]
        grad1=tf.gradients(self.loss, var1)
    with tf.device('/gpu:3'):
        var2=trainable_variables[57:107]
        grad2=tf.gradients(self.loss, var2)
    with tf.device('/gpu:3'):
        optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(
            self.lrn_rate,
            decay=0.9,
            momentum=0.9,
            epsilon=1.0)
        apply_op1 = optimizer.apply_gradients(
            zip(grads, trainable_variables),
            global_step=self.global_step, name='train_step')
```

The above code runs only in gpu:1, since the gradients\ or gradients_1\ namespace only exits in gpu:1, how can this work in multiple gpu?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter, there two solutions:
1.Using this style of code, test memory with different ranging.
2.Reconstructing the gradient() function, using with device() in gradient() function, make the variables initial in different gpus.